# Html helpers for enum in Asp .Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, foreach, html-helper

I have two models classes:

1. Employee.cs

```
    public class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; } 
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public ProjectType Project { get; set; }
    }
```

2. ProjectType.cs

```
    public enum ProjectType
    {
        Project1,
        Project2,
        Project3,
        Project4
    }
```

In the `Create` view for `Employee`, I want to display projects with possibility to check few of them.

I have created a `foreach` loop with `Html.RadioButtonFor` in Create view

```
@model App.Data.Models.Employee
@using App.Data.Models;
    
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
}

<div class="form-horizontal">

<div class="form-group">
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Project, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @foreach (var project in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ProjectType)))
        {
        <div class="col-md-10">

            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Project, project)
            @Html.Label(project.ToString())
        </div>
                }
        </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Which would work just fine if I would be able to choose more than one option. I am assuming that in this case I should create foreach loop with Html.CheckBoxFor and I was trying to do this like in this instruction -> http://findnerd.com/list/view/How-to-bind-checkbox-with-enum-values-in-MVC/25707/

But it didn't really work:
I didn't add anything to ProjectType.cs. I have added one class to Employee.cs

```
 public class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public List<EnumModel> CheckBoxProjectType { get; set; }
    }
    public class EnumModel
    {
        public ProjectType ProjectType { get; set; }
        public bool isSelected { get; set; }
    }
```

And when I was creating a loop in EmployeeController - CheckBoxProjectType was underlined in red:

```
  public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ProjectType model = new ProjectType();
            model.CheckBoxProjectType = new List<EnumModel>();
            foreach (ProjectType projectType in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ProjectType)))
            {
                model.CheckBoxProjectType.Add(new EnumModel() { ProjectType = projectType, isSelected = false });
            }
            return View();
        }
```

In create view I was trying to copy the loop from the link I have posted earlier

```
@model App.Data.Models.Employee
@using App.Data.Models;
    
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
}

<div class="form-horizontal">
    
       <div class="form-group">
      
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.CheckBoxProjectType.Count; i++)
                {
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.CheckBoxProjectType[i].ProjectType);
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.CheckBoxProjectType[i].isSelected);
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CheckBoxProjectType[i].ProjectType);
                }


                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProjectType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Can someone guide me how to create foreach loop for enum?

Comment: Could you please show your code for checkboxes if you want to get help?

Comment: I'm confused as to what your question is. Can you check your post here and clarify it please? Do you want to choose more than one or not? What errors do you have?

Comment: And could you show your model class too, pls?

Comment: I have updated my post with my checkboxes code which doesnt work.

Comment: I want to be able to choose few project. When I am creating new employee I want to choose projects to which he is assigned so then I could display informations about particular project in employee view.

Comment: What is not working means? Can't you display checkboxes? Can't you return your data back?

Comment: When I hover over CheckBoxProjectType program says that " 'ProjectType' does not contain a definition for CheckBoxProjectType and no accesible extention method 'CheckBoxProjectType' accepting argument of type 'ProjectType' could not be found "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see the error already - "i" is not defined and not assigned. How could you compile this?

```
 @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CheckBoxProjectType[i].ProjectType);
```

User just "  Projects  " instead.

And I don't see any @model in your create view  and acton too.

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ProjectType model = new ProjectType();
              //Where is your ProjectType class?
             // and why I see an Employee AS a model in your view?
......
           
       //you have to change your return to this

            return View(model);
        }
```

And it is better idea  to create  a special viewModel like this to use as model (put it in a separate file) :

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
{
        public Employee Employee{ get; set; }
        public List<EnumModel> EnumModels{ get; set; }
 }
```

and your Employee will be:

```
public class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public List<ProjectType > ProjectTypes { get; set; }
    }
```

and your new create action will be like this:

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            var model = new EmployeeViewModel{
                Employee=new Employee, 
                EnumModels=new List<EnumModel>()
               };
           
            foreach (var projectType in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ProjectType)))
            {
                model.EnumModels.Add(new EnumModel { ProjectType = projectType, 
                isSelected = false });
            }
            return View(model);
        }
```

and in your create view replace  Employee by EmployeeModel ( and I think you have to add some Employee input controls too) :

```
@using App.Data.Models
@model EmployeeViewModel
    
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
}

<div class="form-horizontal">
    
       <div class="form-group">
      <h5> Projects </h5>
            <div class="col-md-10">

                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.EnumModels.Count; i++)
                {
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.EnumModels[i].ProjectType);
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.EnumModels[i].isSelected);
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.EnumModels[i].ProjectType);
                }


                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EnumModels, "", new {  
        class = "text-danger" })

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Yes, you are right - i have already placed
```
 @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CheckBoxProjectType[i].ProjectType);
``` 
in my loop. 
I am adding @model to the post.

Comment: I updated my answers too. Pls check them.

Comment: I have two models - one for Employees and one for ProjectType. But in the Create view I use only @model App.Data.Models.Employee. Is it possible to use two models?

Comment: For the create view  you can use  just  Employee class. But it is better Idea to create a special view model. See my answer.

Comment: Could you please tell me where to paste this? In new file? 
For now I still have problem with CheckBoxProjectType prop.

Comment: @izulaa5 I made new EmployeeModelClass and fixed an Employee class. Check my code

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
 public ActionResult Create()
{
    Employee model = new Employee();
    model.CheckBoxProjectType = new List<EnumModel>();
    foreach (ProjectType projectType in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ProjectType)))
    {
       model.CheckBoxProjectType.Add(new EnumModel() { ProjectType = projectType, isSelected = false });
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

and view:

```
@using App.Data.Models.Employee;
    
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
}

<div class="form-horizontal">
    
       <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.CheckBoxProjectType.Count; i++)
                {
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.CheckBoxProjectType[i].ProjectType);
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.CheckBoxProjectType[i].isSelected);
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CheckBoxProjectType[i].ProjectType);
                }

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Still this error:
'Employee' does not contain a definition for 'CheckBoxProjectType' and no accessible extension method 'CheckBoxProjectType' accepting a first argument of type 'Employee' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)